# RxJS5 operator similiar to .combineLatest but fire whenever a single observable emits

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am looking for a way to combine multiple Observables into a flat tuple of scalar values - similar to `.combineLatest()` - but with the exception that it should emit a new value tuple even when no value has been emitted on one of the source observables - yieldung "undefined" in the tuple for those observables that did not yet emit.

Example:

```
const s1 = new Subject<string>();
const s2 = new Subject<string>();

Observable.combineWithUndefined(s1, s2).subscribe( ([t1, t2]) => {
    console.log(t1.toString() + " " + t2.toString());
});

s1.next("Hello");
s2.next("John");

// expected output:
// Hello undefined
// Hello John
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the two subjects [startWith](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) the undefined value, so when one of then emits the first value, the combineLatest will emit as well and combine that with the start value of the other subject.